# JavaScript changes the incorrect element and is not being applied to the desired element

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to this so please forgive my lack of understanding. I have been editing a pen from CodePen and am stuck. I have duplicated and amended the base profile card to have two cards. There is JavaScript that changes what is presented on the card. I am unable to figure out how to have the JS function on the duplicated card. When selecting the buttons on the second card it changes the presentation of the first card. I am wanting to know what I need to change in the JS in order to achieve this. I have scoured the web and have not been able to find a solution. Hopefully, someone here will be able to assist.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".card-buttons button");
const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".card-section");
const card = document.querySelector(".card");

const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
  const targetSection = e.target.getAttribute("data-section");
  const section = document.querySelector(targetSection);
  targetSection !== "#about"
    ? card.classList.add("is-active")
    : card.classList.remove("is-active");
  card.setAttribute("data-state", targetSection);
  sections.forEach((s) => s.classList.remove("is-active"));
  buttons.forEach((b) => b.classList.remove("is-active"));
  e.target.classList.add("is-active");
  section.classList.add("is-active");
};

buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", handleButtonClick);
});

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
      elements[i].onclick = function(){

        // remove class from sibling

        var el = elements[0];
        while(el)
        {
          if(el.tagName === "DIV"){
            //remove class
            el.classList.remove("is-active");                   
          }
          // pass to the new sibling
          el = el.nextSibling;
        }

        this.classList.add("is-active");  
      };
    }
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM+Sans:400,500|Jost:400,500,600&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  color: #2b2c48;
  font-family: "Jost", sans-serif;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566738780863-f9608f88f3a9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2378&q=80);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
}

.card {
  min-width: 340px;
  max-width: 340px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  display: flex;
  transition: 0.3s;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.card[data-state="#about"] {
  height: 550px;
  .card-main {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}

.card[data-state="#contact"] {
  height: 550px;
}

.card[data-state="#experience"] {
  height: 550px;
}

.card.is-active {
  .card-header {
    height: 80px;
  }

  .card-cover {
    height: 100px;
    top: -50px;
  }

  .card-avatar {
    transform: none;
    left: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 10px;
  }

  .card-fullname,
  .card-jobtitle,
  .card-jobtype {
    left: 86px;
    transform: none;
  }

  .card-fullname {
    bottom: 18px;
    font-size: 19px;
  }

  .card-jobtitle {
    bottom: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .card-jobtype {
    bottom: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

.card-header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;

  * {
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
}

.card-cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 160px;
  top: -20%;
  left: 0;
  will-change: top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  filter: blur(30px);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card-avatar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-position: center;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-64px);
}

.card-fullname {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}

.card-jobtitle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-7px);
}

.card-jobtype {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(10px);
}

.card-main {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-subtitle {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.card-content {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.card-desc {
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #636b6f;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
}

.card-social {
  display: flex;
  position: bottom;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  transform: translateX(25%) translateY(350%);
  svg {
    fill: rgb(165, 181, 206);
    width: 16px;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  a {
    color: #8797a1;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: rgba(93, 133, 193, 0.05);
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;

    &:hover {
      svg {
        fill: darken(rgb(165, 181, 206), 20%);
      }
    }

    &:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
}

.card-buttons {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: auto;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  button {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    user-select: none;
    background: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #5c5c6d;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: "Jost", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;

    &.is-active,
    &:hover {
      color: #2b2c48;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #8a84ff;
      background: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(127, 199, 231, 0) 0%,
        rgba(207, 204, 255, 0.2) 44%,
        rgba(211, 226, 255, 0.4) 100%
      );
    }
  }
}

.card-section {
  display: none;
  &.is-active {
    display: block;
    animation: fadeIn 0.6s both;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatey(40px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.card-timeline {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  &:after {
    background: linear-gradient(
      to top,
      rgba(134, 214, 243, 0) 0%,
      rgba(81, 106, 204, 1) 100%
    );
    content: "";
    left: 42px;
    width: 2px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
  }
}

.card-item {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  &:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }

  &:after {
    content: attr(data-year);
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 37px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    line-height: 0.6;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-indent: -35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: rgba(#868686, 0.7);
    background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      lighten(#516acc, 20%) 0%,
      #516acc 100%
    );
  }
}

.card-item-title {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.card-item-desc {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #6f6f7b;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
}

.card-contact-wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-contact {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #6f6f7b;
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  cursor: pointer;

  & + & {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }

  svg {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 30px;
    min-height: 34px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding-right: 12px;
    border-right: 1px solid #dfe2ec;
  }
}

.contact-me {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(83, 200, 239, 0.8) 0%,
    rgba(81, 106, 204, 0.8) 96%
  );
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Jost", sans-serif;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

[class^="grid-item"] {
  color: #6f6f7b;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: none;
}

.grid {
  margin: 0%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 50px);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: none;
  z-index: -2;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-item1 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 45px;
  width: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid #dfe2ec;

  .i {
    color: #dfe2ec;
  }
}

.grid-item2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 45px;
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" data-state="">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-cover" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549068106-b024baf5062d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80')"></div>
    <img class="card-avatar" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549068106-b024baf5062d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80" alt="avatar" />
    <h1 class="card-fullname">#Project Manager</h1>
    <h2 class="card-jobtitle">Leading Brand</h2>
    <h2 class="card-jobtype">{CONTRACT}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-main">
    <div class="card-section <!--is-active-->" id="about">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-subtitle">ABOUT</div>
        <p class="card-desc">Do you have coding experience? Are you a technological professional? Do you strive to break through the barrier of technological limits? <br><br> Our client is looking for a dedicated <strong>#TechnicalProjectManager</strong>. Join a brand leading organisation.
        </p>
        <button class="contact-me">VIEW FULL ROLE OVERVIEW</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-section" id="experience">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-subtitle">THE ROLE</div>
        <p class="card-desc">As a Technical Project Manager, dealing with Management and teams involved on the project is essential. You must also have an ability to understand the Front, Back & Middleware layers of the entire project.</p>
        <br>
        <div class="card-subtitle">THE TEAM</div>
        <p class="card-desc">There is good communication and engagement between management and employees. They offer a positive and encouraging company culture. The team works hard, and the role is fast paced.</p>
        <a href="#"><button class="contact-me">VIEW FULL ROLE OVERVIEW</button></a>
      </div>
    </div class="clear">
    <div class="card-section" id="contact">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-subtitle" style="align:center !important">SUBMIT YOUR CV</div>
        <div class="card-contact-wrapper">
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid-item1"><i class="fal fa-file-upload fa-2x"></i></div>
            <div class="grid-item2">
              <p class="card-contact">Upload your CV</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item1"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item2">
              <p class="card-contact">submit your Cv via WHatsapp</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item1"><i class="fal fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></div>
            <div class="grid-item2">
              <p class="card-contact">drop us an email</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#"><button class="contact-me">VIEW FULL ROLE OVERVIEW</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-buttons">
      <button data-section="#about" <!--class="is-active" -->ABOUT</button>
      <button data-section="#experience">ROLE & TEAM</button>
      <button data-section="#contact">APPLY</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" data-state="">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-cover" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549068106-b024baf5062d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80')"></div>
    <img class="card-avatar" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549068106-b024baf5062d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80" alt="avatar" />
    <h1 class="card-fullname">#Project Manager</h1>
    <h2 class="card-jobtitle">Leading Brand</h2>
    <h2 class="card-jobtype">{CONTRACT}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-main">
    <div class="card-section <!--is-active-->" id="about">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-subtitle">ABOUT</div>
        <p class="card-desc">Do you have coding experience? Are you a technological professional? Do you strive to break through the barrier of technological limits? <br><br> Our client is looking for a dedicated <strong>#TechnicalProjectManager</strong>. Join a brand leading organisation.
        </p>
        <button class="contact-me">VIEW FULL ROLE OVERVIEW</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-section" id="experience">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-subtitle">THE ROLE</div>
        <p class="card-desc">As a Technical Project Manager, dealing with Management and teams involved on the project is essential. You must also have an ability to understand the Front, Back & Middleware layers of the entire project.</p>
        <br>
        <div class="card-subtitle">THE TEAM</div>
        <p class="card-desc">There is good communication and engagement between management and employees. They offer a positive and encouraging company culture. The team works hard, and the role is fast paced.</p>
        <a href="#"><button class="contact-me">VIEW FULL ROLE OVERVIEW</button></a>
      </div>
    </div class="clear">
    <div class="card-section" id="contact">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-subtitle" style="align:center !important">SUBMIT YOUR CV</div>
        <div class="card-contact-wrapper">
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid-item1"><i class="fal fa-file-upload fa-2x"></i></div>
            <div class="grid-item2">
              <p class="card-contact">Upload your CV</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item1"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item2">
              <p class="card-contact">submit your Cv via WHatsapp</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item1"><i class="fal fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></div>
            <div class="grid-item2">
              <p class="card-contact">drop us an email</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#"><button class="contact-me">VIEW FULL ROLE OVERVIEW</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-buttons" id="btns2">
      <button data-section="#about" <!--class="is-active" -->ABOUT</button>
      <button data-section="#experience">ROLE & TEAM</button>
      <button data-section="#contact">APPLY</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

Comment: You're defining just one card at the begining of your script `const card = document.querySelector(".card");`. You need to get the card that clicked button belongs to.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do that? I have looked to see how I can get the id of the element but have been unable to. I have tried to getElementbyID but still doesn't do the trick. The display is still on the first card.

Comment: Sorry, reply wasn't clear. There are going to be a lot of cards and I am wanting to do this with one set of code and variables that will update based on the active card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're using ID for each section in cards and they are duplicated, remember that ID's must be unique. The easiest way to deal with this is by moving ID to dataset, like this:

Original: `<div class="card-section" id="about">`
Change to: `<div class="card-section" data-id="about">`

You are getting just the first card in the global scope `const card = document.querySelector(".card");` but you need to get the card where clicked button belongs to:

```
  // Find the card
  const card = e.target.closest(".card");
```

Now you can get `targetSection` and search for section to activate by it's id stored in dataset:

```
  const targetSection = e.target.getAttribute("data-section");
  // Then find the section by searching for dataset id atribute
  const section = card.querySelector(`[data-id='${targetSection}']`);
```

> Remove `#` from:
>
> - Javascript `targetSection !== "#about"`
> - CSS rules `.card[data-state="#about"]`, same for *experience* and *contact*
> - HTML buttons `<button data-section="#about">ABOUT</button>`, same for *experience* and *contact*

**Update:** To close "inactive" cards, removing `is-active` class is not enough, because you have stiles for `[data-state='some-value'], so, remove that value to make it work.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".card-buttons button");
const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".card-section");
// Get all cards
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
  // First close all the cards
  cards.forEach((c) => {
      c.classList.remove('is-active');
      c.dataset.state = '';
  });
  // I've moved these 2 lines here from below
  sections.forEach((s) => s.classList.remove("is-active"));
  buttons.forEach((b) => b.classList.remove("is-active"));

// Find the card
  const card = e.target.closest(".card");
  const targetSection = e.target.getAttribute("data-section");
  // Then find the section
  const section = card.querySelector(`[data-id='${targetSection}']`);
  targetSection !== "about"
    ? card.classList.add("is-active")
    : card.classList.remove("is-active");
  card.setAttribute("data-state", targetSection);
  e.target.classList.add("is-active");
  section.classList.add("is-active");
};

buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", handleButtonClick);
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM+Sans:400,500|Jost:400,500,600&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  color: #2b2c48;
  font-family: "Jost", sans-serif;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566738780863-f9608f88f3a9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2378&q=80);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
}

.card {
  min-width: 340px;
  max-width: 340px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  display: flex;
  transition: 0.3s;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.card[data-state="about"] {
  height: 550px;
  .card-main {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}

.card[data-state="contact"] {
  height: 550px;
}

.card[data-state="experience"] {
  height: 550px;
}

.card.is-active {
  .card-header {
    height: 80px;
  }

  .card-cover {
    height: 100px;
    top: -50px;
  }

  .card-avatar {
    transform: none;
    left: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 10px;
  }

  .card-fullname,
  .card-jobtitle,
  .card-jobtype {
    left: 86px;
    transform: none;
  }

  .card-fullname {
    bottom: 18px;
    font-size: 19px;
  }

  .card-jobtitle {
    bottom: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .card-jobtype {
    bottom: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

.card-header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;

  * {
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
}

.card-cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 160px;
  top: -20%;
  left: 0;
  will-change: top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  filter: blur(30px);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card-avatar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-position: center;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-64px);
}

.card-fullname {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}

.card-jobtitle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-7px);
}

.card-jobtype {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(10px);
}

.card-main {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-subtitle {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.card-content {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.card-desc {
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #636b6f;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
}

.card-social {
  display: flex;
  position: bottom;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  transform: translateX(25%) translateY(350%);
  svg {
    fill: rgb(165, 181, 206);
    width: 16px;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  a {
    color: #8797a1;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: rgba(93, 133, 193, 0.05);
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;

    &:hover {
      svg {
        fill: darken(rgb(165, 181, 206), 20%);
      }
    }

    &:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
}

.card-buttons {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: auto;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  button {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    user-select: none;
    background: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #5c5c6d;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: "Jost", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;

    &.is-active,
    &:hover {
      color: #2b2c48;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #8a84ff;
      background: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(127, 199, 231, 0) 0%,
        rgba(207, 204, 255, 0.2) 44%,
        rgba(211, 226, 255, 0.4) 100%
      );
    }
  }
}

.card-section {
  display: none;
  &.is-active {
    display: block;
    animation: fadeIn 0.6s both;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatey(40px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.card-timeline {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  &:after {
    background: linear-gradient(
      to top,
      rgba(134, 214, 243, 0) 0%,
      rgba(81, 106, 204, 1) 100%
    );
    content: "";
    left: 42px;
    width: 2px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
  }
}

.card-item {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  &:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }

  &:after {
    content: attr(data-year);
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 37px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    line-height: 0.6;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-indent: -35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: rgba(#868686, 0.7);
    background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      lighten(#516acc, 20%) 0%,
      #516acc 100%
    );
  }
}

.card-item-title {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.card-item-desc {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #6f6f7b;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
}

.card-contact-wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-contact {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #6f6f7b;
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  cursor: pointer;

  & + & {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }

  svg {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 30px;
    min-height: 34px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding-right: 12px;
    border-right: 1px solid #dfe2ec;
  }
}

.contact-me {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(83, 200, 239, 0.8) 0%,
    rgba(81, 106, 204, 0.8) 96%
  );
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Jost", sans-serif;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

[class^="grid-item"] {
  color: #6f6f7b;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: none;
}

.grid {
  margin: 0%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 50px);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: none;
  z-index: -2;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-item1 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 45px;
  width: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid #dfe2ec;

  .i {
    color: #dfe2ec;
  }
}

.grid-item2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 45px;
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" data-state="">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-cover" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549068106-b024baf5062d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80')"></div>
    <img class="card-avatar" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549068106-b024baf5062d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80" alt="avatar" />
    <h1 class="card-fullname">#Project Manager</h1>
    <h2 class="card-jobtitle">Leading Brand</h2>
    <h2 class="card-jobtype">{CONTRACT}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-main">
    <div class="card-section" data-id="about">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-subtitle">ABOUT</div>
        <p class="card-desc">Do you have coding experience? Are you a technological professional? Do you strive to break through the barrier of technological limits? <br><br> Our client is looking for a dedicated <strong>#TechnicalProjectManager</strong>. Join a brand leading organisation.
        </p>
        <button class="contact-me">VIEW FULL ROLE OVERVIEW</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-section" data-id="experience">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-subtitle">THE ROLE</div>
        <p class="card-desc">As a Technical Project Manager, dealing with Management and teams involved on the project is essential. You must also have an ability to understand the Front, Back & Middleware layers of the entire project.</p>
        <br>
        <div class="card-subtitle">THE TEAM</div>
        <p class="card-desc">There is good communication and engagement between management and employees. They offer a positive and encouraging company culture. The team works hard, and the role is fast paced.</p>
        <a href="#"><button class="contact-me">VIEW FULL ROLE OVERVIEW</button></a>
      </div>
    </div class="clear">
    <div class="card-section" data-id="contact">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-subtitle" style="align:center !important">SUBMIT YOUR CV</div>
        <div class="card-contact-wrapper">
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid-item1"><i class="fal fa-file-upload fa-2x"></i></div>
            <div class="grid-item2">
              <p class="card-contact">Upload your CV</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item1"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item2">
              <p class="card-contact">submit your Cv via WHatsapp</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item1"><i class="fal fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></div>
            <div class="grid-item2">
              <p class="card-contact">drop us an email</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#"><button class="contact-me">VIEW FULL ROLE OVERVIEW</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-buttons">
      <button data-section="about" <!--class="is-active" -->ABOUT</button>
      <button data-section="experience">ROLE & TEAM</button>
      <button data-section="contact">APPLY</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" data-state="">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-cover" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549068106-b024baf5062d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80')"></div>
    <img class="card-avatar" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549068106-b024baf5062d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80" alt="avatar" />
    <h1 class="card-fullname">#Project Manager</h1>
    <h2 class="card-jobtitle">Leading Brand</h2>
    <h2 class="card-jobtype">{CONTRACT}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-main">
    <div class="card-section" data-id="about">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-subtitle">ABOUT</div>
        <p class="card-desc">Do you have coding experience? Are you a technological professional? Do you strive to break through the barrier of technological limits? <br><br> Our client is looking for a dedicated <strong>#TechnicalProjectManager</strong>. Join a brand leading organisation.
        </p>
        <button class="contact-me">VIEW FULL ROLE OVERVIEW</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-section" data-id="experience">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-subtitle">THE ROLE</div>
        <p class="card-desc">As a Technical Project Manager, dealing with Management and teams involved on the project is essential. You must also have an ability to understand the Front, Back & Middleware layers of the entire project.</p>
        <br>
        <div class="card-subtitle">THE TEAM</div>
        <p class="card-desc">There is good communication and engagement between management and employees. They offer a positive and encouraging company culture. The team works hard, and the role is fast paced.</p>
        <a href="#"><button class="contact-me">VIEW FULL ROLE OVERVIEW</button></a>
      </div>
    </div class="clear">
    <div class="card-section" data-id="contact">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-subtitle" style="align:center !important">SUBMIT YOUR CV</div>
        <div class="card-contact-wrapper">
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid-item1"><i class="fal fa-file-upload fa-2x"></i></div>
            <div class="grid-item2">
              <p class="card-contact">Upload your CV</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item1"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item2">
              <p class="card-contact">submit your Cv via WHatsapp</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item1"><i class="fal fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></div>
            <div class="grid-item2">
              <p class="card-contact">drop us an email</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#"><button class="contact-me">VIEW FULL ROLE OVERVIEW</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-buttons" id="btns2">
      <button data-section="about">ABOUT</button>
      <button data-section="experience">ROLE & TEAM</button>
      <button data-section="contact">APPLY</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Than you so much. You have helped heaps. Really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, just one last thing. Is there a way to remove the is-active from the active card and add is-active to the newly selected card. I see that the is-active is loaded but not removed from the card. The code I have at the end achieves this but when selecting a card, not via the buttons, it opens a blank page and the previous card remains open.

Comment: Thanks. It is working perfectly. Appreciate your assistance.